# Flattening a list inside a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, flatmap

I am trying to construct a lambda expression which takes in tuples of the form: `(a, b[], c)`, where `b` is a list of elements which needs to be flattened.

For example, the output of the expression should be:
`(a, b[0], c), (a, b[1], c), (a, b[2], c) ...`

I've tried researching and looking for generator expressions that are similar to the situation I've just described, but I can't really wrap my head around this.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) with `zip()` to create the desired tuple for each element in `b`:

```py
from itertools import repeat

f = lambda a, b, c: zip(repeat(a), b, repeat(c))

print(*f(1, [2, 3, 4], 5))
```

This outputs:

```py
(1, 2, 5) (1, 3, 5) (1, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function returning a list comprehension parametrized by the length of the list.

```
func = lambda a, b, c: [(a, b[i], c) for i in range(len(b))]

print(func(1, [2, 3, 4], 5))
```